# Updating a deeply nested object in the state

Tags: reactjs, forms, object, immutability

I am trying to update some Object fields via user input from a form and setting them to the State variable. I've been stuck on figuring out the best method to do this as my fields are structured differently throughout the object. I just want to know a way to handle inputs from user to update the state object dynamically.
    this.state = {
      user: {
        userId:"",

```
    email:{
      data:"",
      p_type: "2"
    },
    fName: {
      data:"",
      p_type: "2"
    },
    lName: {
      data:"",
      p_type: "2"
    },
    number: {
      data:"",
      p_type: "2"
    },

    address:{
      data:{
        street: "",
        suburb: "",
        postcode: ""
      },
      p_type: "1"
    }
  }
```

Above is the object I am trying to update, I have a onChangeHandler and is shown below. obviously the method below does not work for the address attribute but works for the others. Ive tried a few different things to make it work but none are dynamic, and I do not want to create multiple onChangeHandlers as this is just a snapshot of the object and will become a-lot larger.

```
handleChange = event => {
  var updateUser=this.state.user;
  let field =event.target.id
  updateUser[field].data = event.target.value;
  this.setState({user: updateUser });
}
```

Below is the Render code and the code for the form that is used to update the state object

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <FormGroup controlId="address.data.street" bsSize="large">
      <ControlLabel>Street</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl
          type="text"
          value={this.state.user.address.data.street}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
  </FormGroup>
  <FormGroup controlId="address.data.suburb">
      <ControlLabel>Suburb</ControlLabel>
      <FormControl

          type="text"
          value={this.state.user.address.data.suburb}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
  </FormGroup>
```

Open to any suggestions to be honest, as long as the way to handle the inputs via the user are dynamic and could work with any nested attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to note that since the state is immutable, you can not simply just update a nested object in the state. When you do `updateUser[field].data = event.target.value;` in your example, `updateUser` is still the user from the current state - which means this is not allowed.

I recommend using the `icepick` and `lodash` libraries for this, icepick is designed for making updates to nested paths in an **immutable** object (which the state is).

```
import * as i from "icepick";
import * as _ from "lodash";
...


getUserValue = (path) => _.get(this.state.user, path);

setUserValue = (path, value) => {
     const pathArr = _.toPath(path);
     const oldUser = this.state.user;
     const newUser = i.assocIn(oldUser, pathArr, value);
     i.freeze(newUser);
     this.setState({
         user: newUser,
     });
}

render() {
    return (
        <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={getUserValue("address.data.suburb")}
            onChange={e => setUserValue("address.data.suburb", e.target.value)}
        />
    );
}
```

Now this will actually work out of the box, but there is a performance problem here as well - which is that we have a nested arrow function within the render method. This will cause a new function to be created every time react renders, and since the props change react will then re-generate the dom. We can fix this by caching the functions.

The new code, with the function caching is here:

```
import * as i from "icepick";
import * as _ from "lodash";
...


getUserValue = (path) => _.get(this.state.user, path);


setUserValueFnCache = {};
createSetUserValueFn = (path) => {
    if (!!setUserValueFnCache[path]) {
        return setUserValueFnCache[path];
    }

    const fn = (e) => {
        const pathArr = _.toPath(path);
        const oldUser = this.state.user;
        const newUser = i.assocIn(oldUser, pathArr, e.target.value);
        i.freeze(newUser);
        this.setState({
            user: newUser,
        });
    }

    setUserValueFnCache[path] = fn;
    return fn;
}

render() {
    return (
        <FormControl
            type="text"
            value={getUserValue("address.data.suburb")}
            onChange={createSetUserValueFn("address.data.suburb")}
        />
    );
}
```

Now you can see that the arrow function has been removed from our render method, but more importantly, we will give react the same function every time because we've cached the created function. This means React will be able to properly optimize our render for this component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONPath with bind to onChange handler method.

https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

in the bind you can specify JSONPath then use it to update the value in the event handler.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.